# Index and Figure list

Tags: table-of-contents

I 've something like this on a project in ShareLatex. On one side, the table-of-content I have and the other the table-of-content how I want it. I can't find how to do it. I've only worked on ShareLatex, so my knowledge is very limited.

[image: Example of what I have and what I want.]

**Edit**: This code is for change the reference on list of figures and works for list of tables as well. If it doesn't show the name correctly, you can replace `figurename` for `{Name}`.

```
{
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}
\listoffigures
}
```

**Edit2**: This code works to add dots for sections on `article` class

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

Comment: In Spanish `Indice` means `Table of contents`, which isn't [tag:indexing]. The prefix `Figure` should be achievable with the `caption` package. And I hope you're not going to describe the deprecated `subfigure` package...

Comment: You're right, now it's ok. I added a solution but I need the dots of chapters.

Comment: What would you expect in a list of figures? I really don't see the purpose of prepending *Figure* to every entry.

Comment: is the format for reports in my University.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who might have the same question, this is the solution.
This code is for change the reference on list of figures and works for list of tables as well. If it doesn't show the name correctly, you can replace `figurename` for `{Name}`.

```
{
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}
\listoffigures
}
```

This code works to add dots for sections on `article` class

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```